# how to access $rootscope variable in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, scope, controllers, rootscope

I want to assign some data to a global variable (may be $rootscope) which gets initialized at pageload. And then I want to access that data from all the controllers. How would I do that?

```
// Edit : I tried following and it works as expected....

function Ctrl1($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.value = "asdf";
}

function Ctrl2($rootScope, $scope) {
    $scope.value = $rootScope.value;
}
```

Comment: Inject `$rootScope` dependency in your controllers.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Chandermani. Will $rootscope remain common across all the controllers? I mean can I assign something to it in one controller function and access it back from the other controller function? Sorry, I am very new to angularjs (2days old..!)

Comment: Yes absolutely! You can alway try it out. `$rootScope` is the thing closest to global variable in Angular and hence it's use should be minimized. There are other ways to share data, search for angular services.

Comment: Thank you Chandermani. Following works.

function Ctrl1($rootScope) {
 $rootScope.value = "asdf";
}
function Ctrl2($rootScope, $scope) {
 $scope.value = $rootScope.value;
}

Comment: Sharing same data between controllers means sharing data via service . You can use factory for this.

Comment: yes, thanks. Later I figured out that using factory was the best option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MyController($rootScope,$scope)
{
  $rootScope = ....
}
```

you get the point :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to show the variable in the view, there is not need of assign the variable from $rootScope to $scope.